# ng-repeat show default empty value for first option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The ng-repeat show default empty string for first option. Why in may case it does not work. What is wrong in here?

My angular code is here. What i mistake here. I don't understand.

```
var exchange = angular.module('app', []);
exchange.controller('ExchangeController', ExchangeController);

function ExchangeController($scope, $http) {


    $http
        .get(window.location.origin + "/api/get-item/", {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
        })
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.items = response.data.items;
            $scope.send_item_id = $scope.items[0].value;
        });

    $scope.getSendItem = function() {
        var send_item_id = $("#send_item_id").val();
        console.log(send_item_id);
    }

}
```

Here is my html code,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <select data-plugin-selectTwo
                name="send_item_id"
                id="send_item_id"
                ng-model="send_item_id"
                ng-change="getSendItem()"
                class="form-control populate">

            <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="@{{ item.value }}">@{{ item.text }}</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the result data of `response.data.items`. Thanks

Comment: the response result like: [{"text":"Bkash","value":1},{"text":"Paypal","value":2}]

Comment: Thanks, were can we find this `data-plugin-selectTwo` directive?

Comment: I am not sure. I am using a template that was build in here. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually select a "selected" item (`itemSelected` model in my solution) and change your `value` attribute to `ng-value` to make it work in the AngularJS way. Please check this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6s3m6ta/2/)** I've created for you. Btw. you don't need jQuery here: please check how I log the selected item in `getSendItem()`. This will work for `AngularJS 1.6.x` or later.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select data-plugin-selectTwo 
          name="send_item_id" 
          id="send_item_id" 
          ng-model="itemSelected" 
          ng-change="getSendItem()" 
          class="form-control populate">
      <option ng-repeat="item in data" ng-value="item.value">
        @{{ item.text }}
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    "text": "Bkash",
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "text": "Paypal",
    "value": 2
  }];

  $scope.itemSelected = $scope.data[0].value;

  $scope.getSendItem = function() {
    console.log($scope.itemSelected);
  }
});
```

---

### While using AngularJS 1.5.x or earlier you need to do it like in this **[demo fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jm0XwF2iKh3MckwRTpSe?p=preview)** by using `ng-selected`:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <select name="send_item_id" 
          id="send_item_id" 
          ng-model="itemSelected" 
          ng-change="getSendItem()">
    <option
        ng-repeat="item in data" value="{{ item.value }}"
        ng-selected="{{item.value === itemSelected}}">
      {{ item.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.controller('Controller', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    "text": "Bkash",
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "text": "Paypal",
    "value": 2
  }];

  $scope.itemSelected = String($scope.data[0].value);
  console.log($scope.itemSelected);

  $scope.getSendItem = function() {
    console.log($scope.itemSelected);
  }
```

Comment: I have done exact same thing that you did. But in may case it is not working.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir please compare your solution carefully with my codes and you will be fine.

Comment: I understand the logic behind that. My i don't understand why in may case it does not work. Log the selected item form the function work perfectly but when i want to selected for the first element it does not work.

Comment: $http
        .get(window.location.origin + "/api/get-item/", {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false}
        })
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.items = response.data.items;
            $scope.itemSelected = $scope.items[0].value;
        });



    $scope.getSendItem = function() {
        console.log($scope.itemSelected);
    }

Comment: @MahfuzShishir could you create a fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Last i tired with it. <select
        name="send_item_id"
        id="send_item_id"
        ng-model="itemSelected"
        ng-change="getSendItem()"
        class="form-control populate">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="item.value">
        @{{ item.text }}
    </option>
</select>

Comment: @MahfuzShishir please create a fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is a sub part of my project. So cant create fiddle for you. Sorry for that. And Thanks for your response. I create a index.html file and try to run this code: https://pastebin.com/ZGHSJV3G  But i does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @MahfuzShishir we can't help you if you are not able to create a minimal example to reproduce your problem. You should create a fiddle/plnkr with an minimal example of your problem. You don't need to copy your whole apllication into it.

Comment: Ok. This is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/cA4DXGjMrCTiFcJ1ifNy?p=preview

Comment: @MahfuzShishir you are using AngularJS 1.5.x so you need to use `ng-selected ` and ensure datatype by using `String($scope.data[0].value)`. Please check my updated answer. I created a solution for AngularJS 1.6.x and AngularJS 1.5.x or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the option value and `ng-model` value in order to prevent the default empty space. in your case it does not match since there is `@` symbol in front of your option value. remove it.

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{ item.value }}">@{{ item.text }}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's working for me.

```
<option value="{{item.value}}" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="$first">{{ item.text }}</option>
```